# What is the best way to paint an asbestos tile floor?

Tags: flooring, painting, asbestos

I have a studio (1000 sq/ft) where the floor is covered by asbestos tiles, these tiles were previously covered by carpet that I removed.
I am planning to paint the floor to secure it. What would you think would be the best way to do it (paint type/ process)?

Answer (score 1):

Having worked on quite a few older homes after the asbestos information came to the surface we used slightly thinned oil base paint to encapsulate it that was recommended so the paint would soak in and seal it better, when latex was later approved to tell the truth I did not think it covered as well thinned or not but it will cover and encapsulate the tiles. The issue is if the tiles get skuffed some asbestos fibers can be released. I am not sure if anything other than a hard epoxy paint on a floor can really seal it to prevent any problems, next think of all the employees that worked in the many industries that produced asbestos products that are just fine or passed from natural causes. I would never put my family at risk but think anything that encapsulates the tiles will work, if that coating is eroded from use a new coating will be needed to be 100% safe. I believe there is a bit of hype but why take a chance. Use a good quality oil based or latex floor paint and sleep well.